# Android action bar with swipe tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application I have an action bar with swipe tabs like this:

[image: I have something similar to this one]

When I swipe between views the blue stripe moves only after a new view takes the whole screen.

How can I make it move dynamically according to the users swipes? (like in the Google Play, if the screen shows something between two views the stripe will be between the two tabs)

[image]

Comment: This may help you [Android TabNavigation like google play store app using PagerTabStrip](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/tabnvigation-like-google-play-store-app.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Try this code](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) to achieve your objective

Comment: I used this when I learn how to create the action bar and everything. I'm trying to make the stripe move while the user swipes view (if the screen is now showing "TOP RATED" and the user wants to swipe over to the "GAMES" tabs, I want to make the stripe move smoothly to the "GAMES" tab and not just appear there as it does now )

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Tab Swipe Fragmentation Implementation:[Dynamic Swipe Tab](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html)